# Closing Excel Document after Query is Completed

Tags: excel, powerquery, vba

I have a Excel Document with a Query that runs every time it is opened. It will be stored on my companies intranet and the intranet is set up to open the document daily but can only close the document based on a timer.  Is there a way to have the document close when the query has completed running using VBA or settings in excel query?

Comment: User opens spreadsheet; query runs; spreadsheet closes itself. How does anyone actually look at the results of the query?

Comment: How does the query get run? Is there VBA in place to execute the query on worksheet_open or does it just an excel thing that it refreshes the query on open?

Comment: Also, possibly as a follow up to @simon-at-rcl's comment. What is the purpose of opening and refreshing the workbook? Perhaps there is a better way to solve the main problem here that doesn't involve all of the overhead and potential for screwiness that excel presents?

Comment: @simon-at-rcl I have 1000+ files stored in a directory. Files are placed or changed in that directory daily. I have a query that pulls information from each of the files and organizes it into one table. These files are very large and the query can take a while to load so there is a second file that users view that can quickly reference the first file and show users the information they need. The first file is opened every day by a server command and the document is set to refresh on open. The server can only be set to close a doc on a timer.  I need the doc to close when the query is completed

Comment: I tried using VBA to pull information from all these file but found with my limited knowledge in speed optimization the code would take too long. The query only takes a few minutes to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the options for your query and uncheck the box for "Enable Background Loading" and also uncheck the option "Refresh data when opening the file".

Then in the ThisWorkbook module put in

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

RefreshAll
Save
Application.Quit

End Sub
```

And the workbook will refresh the query when it is opened, then save and quit when it is done (if background refreshing is turned off, the VBA code will stop processing until the query is done refreshing).

Mind you this will make it so the workbook always closes after it is done refreshing the query when opened, but you can cntrl-break to stop the macro from running if you need to get in to make changes to your query or something.